# calcular valores de inputs com a mesma class

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso fazer um calculo em tempo real com divs com a mesmoa class inserindo o resultado em outra.

O código qual estou tentando desenvolver está no link abaixo

```js
var qtde_inputs = $('.quant').value;
var soma_inputs = 0;

$('.quant').each(function calcula(i,item){
  var valorItem = parseFloat($(item).val());

  if(!isNaN(valorItem))
    soma_inputs += parseFloat($(item).val());
    
  document.getElementById('seu_campo_destino_da_soma').value = (soma_inputs).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="quant" value="10" onblur="calcula()">
  <input type="text" class="quant" value="10" onblur="calcula()">
  <input type="text" class="quant" value="40" onblur="calcula()">
  
  
  <input type="text" id="seu_campo_destino_da_soma">
<form>
```

Comment: Calculo? que tipo de calculo?

Comment: Eu preciso calcular esses três inputs: 
  <input type="text" class="quant" value="10" onblur="calcula()">
  <input type="text" class="quant" value="10" onblur="calcula()">
  <input type="text" class="quant" value="40" onblur="calcula()">
  
  
  Dando o resultado nesse
  <input type="text" id="seu_campo_destino_da_soma">

Comment: No caso usar o JS para somar os inputs com class quant em tempo real dando o resultado no input total, caso seja necessario crio um i++ para gerar um quant diferente, mas que seja automatico buscar entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você colocar o seu calculo em uma **função** e chamar essa função todas vez que um de seus `<input />` da classe quant for alterado.

```js
$('.quant').on("blur", Soma);

function Soma(){
  var soma = 0;
 $('.quant').each(function(){
    var valorItem = parseFloat($(this).val());

    if(!isNaN(valorItem))
      soma += parseFloat(valorItem);
  });
  
  $('#soma').val((soma).toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="quant" value="0">
    +
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="quant" value="0">
    +
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="quant" value="0">
    +
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="soma" value="0">
  </div>
<form>
```

Comment: Não me expressei muito bem, eu precisaria contatenar porque cada quant teria um $i++, o script deveria ficar em algo tipo isso, porem não consegui fazer funcionar
<script type='text/javascript'>


    $('#total'+index).on("blur", Soma);

    function Soma(){
        var soma = 0;
        $('#total'+index).each(function(){
        var valorItem = parseFloat($(this).val());

        if(!isNaN(valorItem))
             soma += parseFloat(valorItem);
        });
  
        $('#resultado').val((soma).toFixed(2));
    }   

        
    </script>

Comment: Esse e o codigo qual estou trabalhando, preciso fazer com que o total que cada produto seja calculado e todos os totais sejam somados no id final https://anotepad.com/note/read/pw5nqb

Comment: Cara, o meu exemplo soma os 3 inputs e totaliza no ultimo, não estou compreendo o que você quer fazer, ao invés de mostrar o código fala o que você espera que o código faça, exemplo: "tenho 3 campos e deseje que a soma deles seja exibida no ultimo"

Comment: Eu tenho um sistema que gera formulario pros clientes preencherem certo, e no caso a gente gera o total de produtos e cada um contatena gerando um Total, digamos que inseri dois produtos vai ficar total0 e total1. Assim em diante, e preciso fazer com que todos esses totais sejam somados e apareçam no id Final

Comment: Desculpa, não tenho como te ajudar, para mim ainda não está claro o que você quer, é difícil para quem está de fora imaginar seu cenário se você não for especifico e sucinto

Comment: pelo que você disse e pelo que @CaiqueRomero respondeu, eu creio assim como ele que sua pergunta já tem solução, pelo menos a lógica você pode ter base e tentar estudar e melhorar a fim de adaptar ao seu código, mas o que ele fez está ótimo

Comment: sim está otimo, só estou apanhando para fazer com que interaja com meu codigo, sera que você não conseguiria me passar um contato para explicar melhor e tentar resovler? é um projeto para aumento em uma empresa qual trabalho

Answer (score -1):

precisa criar uma variavel que fique recebendo valores durante o fluxo.

```
var val = document.getelementbyid('')

val = val + val
```

coloca isso num while

e no final motra o valor.